# Use the users iOS currency settings

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working with currency in an app and instead of listing out supported currencies or using `Locale.isoCurrencyCodes` to list out all currencies supported by iOS I would like to just use the currency that the user selects as their default system currency.

Is there a good way to do this or what's the best way to support multiple currencies in an iOS app?

For added context the application is written in Swift.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted as it seems like a legitimate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Local currency code**:

```swift
let usrRegionCode = Locale.current.currencyCode!
```

E.g.: `"USD"`

---

**Local currency symbol**:

```swift
let usrRegionCode = Locale.current.currencySymbol!
```

E.g.: `"$"`

Comment: Thank you, that actually does help solve a good portion of my problem.